# Rails opentelemetry-sdk with Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, open-telemetry

Is possible to configure the gem [opentelemetry-sdk](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-ruby) to send telemetry data to the [Elasticsearch APM server](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/apm)?

I've setup my Rails app in this way:

In Gemfile I've add the following gems:

```
gem 'opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'
gem 'opentelemetry-instrumentation-all'
gem 'opentelemetry-sdk'
```

In `config/initializers` I've add a new file `opentelemetry.rb` with this content:

```rb
require 'opentelemetry/sdk'
require 'opentelemetry/instrumentation/all'
require 'opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'

OpenTelemetry::SDK.configure do |c|
  c.service_name = 'my_app_name'
  c.logger = Rails.logger
  c.use_all

  c.add_span_processor(
    OpenTelemetry::SDK::Trace::Export::SimpleSpanProcessor.new(
      OpenTelemetry::Exporter::OTLP::Exporter.new(
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:8200/',
        headers: { 'Authorization' => 'Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN' }
      )
    )
  )
end

Tracer = OpenTelemetry.tracer_provider.tracer('my_app_name')
```

Now in my code I've add something like this:

```
Tracer.in_span 'fn1' do |span|
  # do work
end
```

Then I run the APM server with the command: `./apm-server -c apm-server.yml -e`.

My `apm-server.yml` file is:

```
apm-server:
  host: "localhost:8200"
  auth:
    secret_token: qwerty

  kibana:
    enabled: true
    host: "localhost:5601"

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

The APM start and I got no errors.

When the Rails `Tracer.in_span` code run I can see in the APM output something like this:

```
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-12-15T15:24:47.035+0100","log.logger":"request","log.origin":{"file.name":"middleware/log_middleware.go","file.line":63},"message":"request ok","service.name":"apm-server","url.original":"/","http.request.method":"POST","user_agent.original":"Ruby, OTel-OTLP-Exporter-Ruby/0.26.1 Ruby/3.2.2 (arm64-darwin22; ruby/3.2.2)","source.address":"127.0.0.1","http.request.body.bytes":497,"http.request.id":"87bdb9b6-548f-4719-a608-6d7b5130532a","event.duration":318125,"http.response.status_code":200,"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
```

But in Kibana I don't find any trace. If I switch from the Ruby opentelemetry-sdk gem to the [official Elasticsearch gem elastic-apm](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-ruby) and replace the `Tracer.in_span` code with

```
ElasticAPM.with_span 'f1' do |span|
  # do work
end
```

all works, and I can see the trace on Kibana.

But I don't like the `ElasticAPM` gem because is limited and you cannot add searchable attributes to spans and add events.

Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

Using `ElasticAPM.with_span` works because the Elastic APM gem is designed to communicate directly with the [Elasticsearch APM](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/apm) server. But you may need additional setup for [OpenTelemetry data](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otlp/) to be recognized.

Do increase the logging level of both your Rails app and the APM server to get more insight into where the disconnect might be.

There is an official "[Elasticsearch OpenTelemetry integration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/open-telemetry.html)" guide. So try and follow the "[Send data from an OpenTelemetry agent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/open-telemetry-direct.html#instrument-apps-otel)" section, especially the section about environment variables, to configure the OpenTelemetry agent and enable communication with Elastic APM.